# How to cleanly package a Typescript top-level external module

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a NPM package written in Typescript. Here's how I've currently packaged all of its classes and interfaces. This works but seems to be quite repetitive and not very clean (particularly the empty class and interface extensions). How could I improve this?

*Edit: I've changed the main NPM file to use class extensions. This makes everything more maintainable since there is no repetition anymore. But it probably slower since every class is effectively defined twice.*

deck.ts (the main NPM file)

```
/// <reference path="../d.ts/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts" />

import DeckDatabasePostgresClient = require('./Database/Postgres/Client');
import DeckDatabasePostgresConfigInterface = require('./Database/Postgres/ConfigInterface');
import DeckApp = require('./App');
import DeckRoute = require('./Route');
import DeckRouter = require('./Router');

module Deck {
    export module Database.Postgres {
        export class Client extends DeckDatabasePostgresClient {}
        export interface ConfigInterface extends DeckDatabasePostgresConfigInterface {}
    }
    export class App extends DeckApp {}
    export class Route extends DeckRoute {}
    export class Router extends DeckRouter {}
}

export = Deck;
```

Is something similar to the following possible in Typescript?

```
module Deck {
    export import App = require('./App');
}
```

Currently, this results in the following error:

```
Import declarations in an internal module cannot reference an external module.
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe classes are first class citizens in TypeScript. e.g:

```
class Foo{}

var bar = Foo; 
var baz = new bar(); 

// Same as :
var bar: typeof Foo = Foo; 
var baz:Foo = new bar();
```

So, you can do something along the lines of :

```
class DeckClass{};

export = DeckClass

declare module 'Deck'{
    export var DeckClass:typeof DeckClass;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. At first, I thought it worked, since it compiled just fine. But it doesn't seem to work. If I was to do something like this: `var instance: DeckClass = new DeckClass(); instance.someMethod(5); // a string is expected as the param, not a number`, I get no compiler warning. I do get one if I extend use an empty class extension like my example.

Comment: @conradk you are right. seems like a compiler bug : http://goo.gl/NBBwto possibly report it here : http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic Would appreciate a link to the bug if you post it so that I can vote on it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the bug is actually. We mean this, right: http://goo.gl/YCzAib. Also, I've updated the example in the original question. Seems like I dont even need a d.ts file after all.

Comment: I thought the error is that despite `var DeckClass: typeof DeckClass;` var DeckClass is of type `any` and not the class DeckClass. I figured it is because of name shadowing. Once the variable DeckClass was declared locally the actual class declaration was shadowed

Comment: If that was the case, then I don't understand why this code does not work (or maybe this is expected behavior?): http://goo.gl/Hb9XDb

Comment: @conradk yes, but the type is still DeckClass, or you can let the compiler infer it for you : http://goo.gl/eBppCA